# Removing TextBox , Location issue C#

Tags: c#, dynamic, textbox, trackbar

I want to create textboxes dynamically on **trackbar_scroll**. If **trackbar** has a value of 5, it may have 5 textboxes. When it decreases to 2, it must have 2 textboxes. Here is the problem when I decrease trackbar_scroll value:

```
private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls) // to remove all textboxes before creating new
        {
            if (ctrl is TextBox)
            {
                this.Controls.Remove(ctrl);
                ctrl.Dispose();
            }
        }

        int x = 45; // location for textbox

        for (int i = 0; i < trackBar1.Value; i++)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(i);
            TextBox _text = new TextBox();
            _text.Name = "txt"+i;
            _text.Height = 20;
            _text.Width = 100;
            _text.Text = _text.Name;

            _text.Location = new Point(x, 85);
            this.Controls.Add(_text);
            x = x + 120;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't modify the list as you for-each over it, but you can if you use a copy of the list:

```
foreach (TextBox tb in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList()) {
  tb.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: thanks , it works. Would you like to elaborate please. What is difference between 
foreach ( control ctrl in this.Controls)
and your code.

Comment: @A.RShaib The real difference is the `ToList()` which makes a copy of the list.  In your original code, removing a control from the collection changes the collection, so the next control is off by one, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to modify `this.Controls` while iterating over it via `foreach`.  This is now allowed, as it causes bookkeeping problems.  To fix your bug, either iterate backwards through the list with a for loop that starts at the end, or use a temporary list to store controls you intend to remove and then iterate over that list to actually remove them.